# How to configure PrimeVue multiselect to add a "line break" instead of cutting off the overlapping ones?

Tags: vue.js, primevue

I'm using Vue3 with PrimeVue and have a lot of items in a [multiselect component](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/multiselect). Based on the sample code: When selecting all items it will cut off the overlapping ones with three dots

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- PrimeVue -->
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@2.0.0/primeflex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/core/core.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Demo -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/multiselect/multiselect.min.js"></script>
        <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <p-multiselect v-model="selectedCities" :options="cities" option-label="name" placeholder="Select Cities" display="chip"></p-multiselect>
        </div>

        <script type="module">
        const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

        const App = {
            setup() {
                const selectedCities = ref();
                const selectAll = ref(false);
                const cities = ref([
                    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
                    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
                    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
                    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
                    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
                ]);

                return { selectedCities, cities, selectAll }
            },
            methods: {
                onSelectAllChange(event) {
                    this.selectedItems = event.checked ? this.items.map((item) => item.value) : [];
                    this.selectAll = event.checked;
                },
                onChange(event) {
                    this.selectAll = event.value.length === this.items.length
                }
            },
            components: {
                "p-multiselect": primevue.multiselect
            }
        };

        createApp(App)
            .use(primevue.config.default)
            .mount("#app");
        </script>

        <style>
        .p-multiselect {
            width: 18rem;
        }

        .multiselect-custom .p-multiselect-label:not(.p-placeholder) {
            padding-top: .25rem;
            padding-bottom: .25rem;
        }

        .multiselect-custom .country-item-value {
            padding: .25rem .5rem;
            border-radius: 3px;
            display: inline-flex;
            margin-right: .5rem;
            background-color: var(--primary-color);
            color: var(--primary-color-text);
        }

        .multiselect-custom .country-item-value img.flag {
            width: 17px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
            .p-multiselect {
                width: 100%;
            }
        }
        </style>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Three dots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMOEW.png)

When removing the CSS the component simply grows

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0" />

        <!-- PrimeVue -->
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/resources/primevue.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeflex@2.0.0/primeflex.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://unpkg.com/primeicons/primeicons.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/core/core.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Demo -->
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/primevue@^3/multiselect/multiselect.min.js"></script>
        <link href="./index.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
            <p-multiselect v-model="selectedCities" :options="cities" option-label="name" placeholder="Select Cities" display="chip"></p-multiselect>
        </div>

        <script type="module">
        const { createApp, ref } = Vue;

        const App = {
            setup() {
                const selectedCities = ref();
                const selectAll = ref(false);
                const cities = ref([
                    {name: 'New York', code: 'NY'},
                    {name: 'Rome', code: 'RM'},
                    {name: 'London', code: 'LDN'},
                    {name: 'Istanbul', code: 'IST'},
                    {name: 'Paris', code: 'PRS'}
                ]);

                return { selectedCities, cities, selectAll }
            },
            methods: {
                onSelectAllChange(event) {
                    this.selectedItems = event.checked ? this.items.map((item) => item.value) : [];
                    this.selectAll = event.checked;
                },
                onChange(event) {
                    this.selectAll = event.value.length === this.items.length
                }
            },
            components: {
                "p-multiselect": primevue.multiselect
            }
        };

        createApp(App)
            .use(primevue.config.default)
            .mount("#app");
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

[Grow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sc3XD.png)

Is there a way to configure this component to add a "line break" instead of cutting off the overlapping ones?

What I want to achieve can be found here

- Element Plus: https://element-plus.org/en-US/component/select.html#basic-multiple-select

[Element Plus Multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pAApm.png)

- Vuetify: https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects/#multiple

[Vuetify Multiselect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgBcp.png)

Answer (score 4):

changes you need to make here...

```css
.p-multiselect {
  min-width: 17rem;
}
.p-multiselect-label {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.p-multiselect-token {
  margin: 0.1rem;
}
```

result:
[image]